# Obtain variable value as a Ruby expression in String

Tags: ruby

If I have a variable of a basic String/integer/float value, or a hash/array of these basic values, how to get its expression as a String?

If it is a string, I want `'"foo"'`. If it is an Integer, I want `"1"`.

Basically I want the opposite of `eval()`. Currently I use `inspect` but it feels fragile.

---

Update:

I need to take user input, and output a .rb file containing that input. For exmple this erb file:

```rb
a = <%= variable %>
```

So if a user input a string, then in the .rb file I need to include that string in Ruby expression, e.g. `a = "foo"` or `a = 1`.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. If it is already a string then it would return that string, if it is already an integer then it would return that integer. Therefore I do not understand the problem you are trying to solve. Would you mind elaborating and adding better examples of inputs and the expected outputs?

Comment: Agreed. As far as I can tell, it sounds like `#inspect` is exactly what you want.

Comment: @spickermann I will receive a dynamic variable from user input, and output that as part of a .rb file. Therefore I need to have that value in Ruby expression form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inspect` is the closest built-in method available. For the types you listed (integer, float, string, array, and hash) its output resembles a [literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) that will evaluate to an equivalent object. It's the very same value you get from IRB when inspecting a value – those can be copy-and-pasted back into Ruby.

The only exceptions I'm aware of are `Float::NAN` and (+/-) `Float::INFINITY` which print as `NaN` and `Infinity`.

Note that you can't set any output options, though. For example, [`String#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#inspect-method) will always use double quotes, regardless of its characters. [`Hash#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#inspect-method) will always use the `key => value` "hash rocket" syntax even if all keys are symbols.

That said, a Ruby expression generated via `inspect` will work for those core objects but it might not generate the most succinct literals.